# ios Get table view cell index when edit action is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have a table view that has cells with edit actions. When the user swipes one of the cells to the left, you can see the edit action buttons.

[image]

When the user taps one of the buttons, I need to get the index path of the cell that the buttons were clicked from. How can I do that?

**NOTE**, the edit action buttons arn't UIButtons, they are made like this.

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Reply" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {

 nil;

                                    }];

    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.4 blue:0.9 

    alpha:1.0]; //arbitrary color
    }
```

Comment: can you update cellForRowAtIndexPath code it will be easier to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override delegate method, which will get when you swipe row for edit/delete options.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSLog(@"canEditRowAtIndexPath get called");
        NSLog(@"Index is %ld",indexPath.row);
        return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //delete object here
        NSLog(@"Index is %ld",indexPath.row);
        [tableView reloadData]; // tell table to refresh now
   }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method get called");
    NSLog(@"Index is %ld",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented both methods however the second one isn't calling? I'm not sure if the action buttons are accessories, I used this method to create them. `-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: I re updated my post with a more accurate description.

Comment: @Josh Hi , just updated answer please check now, this will give you the  index while clicking on delete button index

Answer (score 0):

first set

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{......
editbutton.tag=index.row
   [editbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

....
}
```

than 
in

```
-(IBAction)clickOn:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    nslog(@"%d",btn.tag);


}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think I was clear enough so you could understand. I re updated my answer with a note, please look at it so you can understand the question better.

Comment: okay fine       do like  this in your                                                                        -(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {                                           
                       [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];                                 }

Answer (score -1):

Try this

write this in your `UITableViewCell`

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Referencing superviews in built-in classes is bad practice because Apple can change the structure of the views and the application will be broken.